# R Shiny - mysql connection doesn't work from server.R (works from other files)

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, rstudio, shiny-server

I have a Shiny app in RStudio, which works with data I retrieve from a mysql database.

The connection to mysql and the queries are in a file outside the app, so I can create dataframes.

But when I copy the connection to mysql and the sql queries into `server.R` of the Shiny app, the app skips the queries and gives an error that the dataframe does not exist (`Error : object 'tickets' not found`).

So the mysql query works from outside `server.R`, but not from `server.R`. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a sample of my server.R and ui.R :

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(RMySQL)
library(ggplot2)
#library(ggiraph)
library(lubridate)

##Connect to Redmine db
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 user = '#',
                 password = '#',
                 host = '#',
                 dbname='#')

tickets<-dbGetQuery(con, "Select * from table")
issues_speed_unique<-unique(na.omit(dbGetQuery(con,"Select * from table2")))
dbDisconnect (con) 

some aggregations....

shinyServer(
  function(input,output){
     output$tickets_week<-renderPlot(
          ggplot(data = subset(tickets,
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
#library(ggiraph)
#library(htmltools)
library(lubridate)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
```

Comment: if you add `print(tickets)` under the query and run the app, does the data frame print to console?

Comment: @Pete900 sorry, late reply. nope, doesn't show. it seems it skips directly to  what's inside `shinyServer(
  function(input,output){` .

Comment: Will it work when you launch the app by browser compared to just running in RStudio?

Comment: @Pete900 thanks for the hint ´print(tickets)´ . It helped with debugging. Please see the solution I found.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem** was that `ui.R` was run *before* `server.R`, and of course the data was missing (because the data was queried in `server.R`- hence the error).

**The solution** was to put the code, both from `server.R` and from `ui.R`, in one file, called `app.R`. So, in `app.R` I wrote the code in the following order:

1. Load packages (`library(packagename)`) code
2. Make connection and queries code
3. the *server* code
4. the *ui* code
5. finish code with: `shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`

More about Shiny in a single file - `app.R` file: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/single-file.html